# Best approach for percolation, depth first search or union find?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Which approach is the best for the percolation problem, Depth first search or Union find? What are the time complexities of these two algorithms?

Comment: Is this a homework question? What have you tried?

Comment: It was for an assignment. I tried it with depth first search but it gives me O(n^3) running time

Answer (score 0):

You may consider reading those about percolation problem :

- http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/24percolation/
- http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/lectures/15UnionFind.pdf

First one presents the problem and solution using dfs, second using union-find. As for the running time, it would require some benchmark to find the best way.